# could not converting string to float

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am working with python 3.7

```
x='5,3'
x= float(x.replace(',','.'))
```

It works fine, but I have bigger number

```
x='5,003,313'
x= float(x.replace(',','.')) ---> error : could not converting string to float
```

how can I convert such string to a number

Comment: In the bigger number when you replace comma with . you end up having two dots, which is not valid: 5.003.313. What is your expected float number? 5003.313?

Comment: Are the commas supposed to be thousands separators, or decimal points? If they're supposed to be both, you're going to have trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex sub function to replace comma to nothing and then convert it to float, like this:

```
import re
value = '5,003,313'
parsed_value = re.sub(r'\,', '', value)
float_value = float(parsed_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `x.replace(',','.')` on `'5,003,313'` the result is `5.003.313` which is not a valid number format.

You might also be confusing the use of the comma and the decimal point (some countries use the comma for the decmial) so be sure to examine that carefully.

*If this answered your question please select the green checkmark*

Answer (score 0):

So a quik answer, to convert a string to a number :

```
str='203.65'
flt=float(str)
int=int(round(flt))
```